# Get only the top element with getElementsByTagName in PHP

Tags: php, domdocument

Using `getElementsByTagName()` of `DomDocument` returns a `DOMNodeList` object containing all the elements with supplied tag name, like this -:
`$pTag = $doc->getElementsByTagName('p');`

But how do I get just the first `p tag` in the document and not all the `p tags`.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$pTag = $doc->getElementsByTagName('p')[0]
```

or this:

```
$pTag = $doc->getElementsByTagName('p')->item(0)
```